# Outputting JSON with the MSSqlServer Serilog sink

Tags: sql-server, serilog

How can I configure the MSSqlServer Serilog sink to output the properties as JSON instead of XML? I tried passing a `RenderedCompactJsonFormatter` to the `formatProvider` parameter of `LoggerConfigurationMSSqlServerExtensions.MSSqlServer()`, but that expects an `IFormatProvider`.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use the LogEvent column and pull the Properties object out of that JSON.

Comment: @squillman Thanks, I just found that. If you want to add that as an answer, I'll accept it. I'm trying this right now: columnOptions.Store.Add(StandardColumn.LogEvent);

Comment: Why did you choose to log to SQL Server? Why not log to Seq?

Comment: @mason Setting up Seq in this environment would be complicated and pricey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could instead use the LogEvent column and pull the Properties object out of the JSON in that column value.

```
var colOpts = new ColumnOptions();
colOpts.Store.Add(StandardColumn.LogEvent);
colOpts.Store.Remove(StandardColumn.Properties);
var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
              .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(connString, "Logs",columnOptions:colOpts)
              .CreateLogger();
```

Note, I also removed the Properties column so as not to duplicate data in the table.

Comment: You might want to ask the question https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver/issues/1

Answer (score 1):

To do it by config using WriteTo Args for Serilog.Sink.MSSqlServer.

```
"Args": {
    "tableName": "TestMvcClient",
    "schemaName": "dbo",
    "autoCreateSqlTable": true,
    "columnOptionsSection": {
        "addStandardColumns": [ "LogEvent" ], /* Use JSON Column LogEvent */
        "removeStandardColumns": [ "Properties" ], /* Remove XML Column Properties */
    }
}
```

You can find it and 20+ other settings at the Serilog source.
https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver#custom-property-columns